# Draw arc using relative coordinates with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

My quetion may be dumb, but consider that I am very new with Tikz.

I am trying to draw a tower similar to Eifel using the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[{x=(1mm,0)},{y=(0,1mm)}]
\def\towerwd{5}                 % tower width
\def\towerht{10}                % tower height
\def\towerar{4*\towerwd/10}     % tower arc radius

\def\tower#1{% #1=position
    \draw[thick]
        %... tower arc
        {#1++(-\towerar,0)}
            arc(180:0:\towerar)--
            (\towerwd/2,0) to[out=120,in=270]
            (0,\towerht) to[out=270,in=60]
            (-\towerwd/2,0)--
            cycle
        ;
    }

\tower{(0,0)} % this works!
\tower{(0,20)} % this is messy!
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

It works fine when I do `\tower{(0,0)}`, but becomes messy when I use any other coordinate. **What am I doing wrong here?**

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippet that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). It is much easier to help you if we can start with some compilable code that illustrates your problem. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, include any necessary packages and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. At the moment we have to guess what packages etc you are using before we can compile your code.

Comment: Yes, sure! I will edit my question. Thank you, @Andrew

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It becomes messy because `++` does not add these coordinates, you might use `calc` for that *if there was not a (IMHO) much more elegant way*: `pic`s.

What do `pic`s do? A pic is, as its name suggests, a small picture like your tower. `pic`s can be placed and transformed. All I did was to move your `\tower` code inside the definition of a `pic` by saying

```
 \tikzset{pics/.cd,
    tower/.style={code={
        \draw[thick]
            (-\towerar,0)
                arc(180:0:\towerar)--
                (\towerwd/2,0) to[out=120,in=270]
                (0,\towerht) to[out=270,in=60]
                (-\towerwd/2,0)--
                cycle
            ;
    }}}
```

Here, the `.cd` switches to the `pics` subdirectory of pgfkeys `tikz` directory. The rest is just to teach Ti*k*Z the tower code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{pics/.cd,
tower/.style={code={
    \draw[thick]
        (-\towerar,0)
            arc(180:0:\towerar)--
            (\towerwd/2,0) to[out=120,in=270]
            (0,\towerht) to[out=270,in=60]
            (-\towerwd/2,0)--
            cycle
        ;
}}}

\begin{tikzpicture}[{x=(1mm,0)},{y=(0,1mm)}]
\def\towerwd{5}                 % tower width
\def\towerht{10}                % tower height
\def\towerar{4*\towerwd/10}     % tower arc radius
\path (0,0) pic{tower} (0,20) pic{tower};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

But this example does not at all explain why people are excited about pics. Rather, you might want to add parameters instead of the somewhat clumsy `\def\towerwd{5}` and so on statements. And you may want to change parameters from "outside". All this can be done with `pic`s.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{pics/.cd,
tower/.style args={#1 wide and #2 high}{code={
    \draw[thick]
        (-4*#1/10,0)
            arc(180:0:4*#1/10)--
            (#1/2,0) to[out=120,in=270]
            (0,#2) to[out=270,in=60]
            (-#1/2,0)--
            cycle
        ;
}}}

\begin{tikzpicture}[{x=(1mm,0)},{y=(0,1mm)}]
\path (0,0) pic{tower=5 wide and 15 high}
node[below]{Paris} (20,2) pic[rotate=-30,blue]{tower=5 wide and 10 high}
node[below]{Pisa};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, @marmot. Thank you very much for the answer. It works perfectly. Could you please explain the role of `\tikzset` and its arguments `pics/.cd` and `tower/.style`? Thank you again.

Comment: @Brasil I added explanations and a more advanced example.

Comment: Yeah... sorry. In a hurry, I missed the explanations. Everything is very new for me, so I think I will need to read a bit of external explantions too. Let me a final question: is there any difference if I do `\tikzset` inside the `tikz` environment? Thank you again, @marmot. Its great!

Comment: @Brasil The answer is: yes and no. No because `\tikzset` works, in principle, always the same. Yes because its definitions are not global. In your example you have `\def\towerwd{5}` *inside* the `tikzpicture`, so `\towerwd` is not known outside because by default definitions are not global. Same thing for pgfkeys: the key value is not known outside the `tikzpicture` if you set it inside.

Comment: Hi @marmot. Is it possible to rotate the tower in the first example? I am trying a similar code, but I don't get the rotation.

Comment: @Brasil Yes. If I use in the first example `\path (0,0) pic{tower} (0,20) pic[rotate=30]{tower};`, the upper tower gets rotated, as expected.

Comment: Thank you @marmot. I might be doing something wrong. I'll try to figure out.